# Invalid RunAs Account

Tags: administration, installation

Only the system account is working (without the domain). This error is weird.

[image]

I am very sure that the format is correct and the user is existing in Active Directory. This error message is not very informative. Has anyone encountered this yet?

Answer (score 0):

The connection between the SharePoint server and the Active Directory is faulty. I rejoined the SharePoint server in the domain.